# Battery changed broadcast receiver crashing app on some phones

Tags: android

I activate my application whenever the phone get plugged in a power source.
This is my manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is my broadcast receiver

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Just received connection broadcast");


        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter); //this line is causing the crash


        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, 0);
```

Now, the line causing the crashing on my friends phone (on mine everything is working perfectly) is this one

```
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

Can someone please tell me what is the reason and how to fix it?
My phone is a galaxy nexus with the latest android JB, his phone is a LG optimus one with gingerbread

Here is the logcat

```
    02-27 01:25:19.399: D/AndroidRuntime(5326): Shutting down VM
02-27 01:25:19.399: W/dalvikvm(5326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.doublep.wakey.PowerConnectionReceiver: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1926)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326): Caused by: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:151)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:145)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at com.doublep.wakey.PowerConnectionReceiver.onReceive(PowerConnectionReceiver.java:46)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1915)
02-27 01:25:19.419: E/AndroidRuntime(5326):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: maybe this would help [Android: Get Battery Status at regular intervals using alarm manager][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306354/android-get-battery-status-at-regular-intervals-using-alarm-manager/22624565#22624565

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a [`ReceiverCallNotAllowedException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ReceiverCallNotAllowedException.html).

> This exception is thrown from `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver,
>   IntentFilter)` and `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)` when
>   these methods are being used from an BroadcastReceiver component. In
>   this case, the component will no longer be active upon returning from
>   receiving the Intent, so it is not valid to use asynchronous APIs.

This means, that you can't register a `BroadcastReceiver` *inside* a `BroadcastReceiver`.

**Edit:**
Working example for a BroadcastReceiver, which listens to the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` Intent:

```
    private int mBatteryLevel;
    private IntentFilter mBatteryLevelFilter;

    BroadcastReceiver mBatteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mBatteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Current Battery Level: " + mBatteryLevel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    private void registerMyReceiver() {
        mBatteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBatteryReceiver, mBatteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

Now you just have to call `registerMyReceiver()`.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how i can retrieve the battery status(if is charging or not) from the broadcast receiver? getting the battery status from intent gives me always as not charging

Comment: @Ahmad the code you show is a java class? where do you call the method registerMyReceiver() ? In the same scope I don´t know how to declare it in Manifiest. Thanks in advanced so can learn it the practical way.