# OnReceive Battery(how to track every 1%)

Tags: android

I have simple broadcaster that listens for ON_CHANGE event, so my main question is why my phone sometimes jumps down not by 1% but by 2%, 3% or 4%?

And it sometime feels like phone sleeps and does not receive that intent, but after some time it is back from sleep and gets not 1% but 4%
**EDIT**

```
   /* Broadcast Receiver for battery stats                                               */
            IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);


            batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                    int isCharging = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

......

    registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
```

Comment: post your registerReceiver() and pertinent code and your broadcastReceiver.

Comment: As Ahmad has said that looks good in my opinion...

Comment: yeah :) in my opinion too :)

Comment: the broadcast receiver should always give you the battery percent at each 1% interval (though I didn't know about the Mortarola thing). At least it has for me in the past week of using it.

Comment: Yes, I would think so too, because events like temperature and etc. happens faster than battery level decrease :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so my main question is why my phone sometimes jumps down not by 1% but
>   by 2%, 3% or 4%?

This shouldn't happen. Usually the broadcast will get fired up after the battery got drained by 1%(or the battery status changes in general). There is one exception though. On some Motorola devices the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` will get fired up only every 10%. For a working example of a Broadcastreceiver, which listenst to the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102124/battery-changed-broadcast-receiver-crashing-app-on-some-phones/15102295#15102295) I gave a while back.

> but after some time it is back from sleep and gets not 1% but 4%

The Broadcastreceiver does not wake up your phone, so this is not unusual :)

Comment: So maybe it's just my samsung pocket? :)

Comment: AFAIK the 10% thing only occurs on some Motorola devices. Your edited code also looks fine

Comment: Hmm... then I am out of ideas

Comment: I know that :D, that was expression :)

Comment: Hmm.. are you using that in a service, Appwidgetprovider(for an Appwidget) or just in an Activity?

Comment: Activity :). But this jump happens not all the time :) mostly it is dripping by one, but as I said sometimes :)

Comment: Maybe it's something device specific after all. Could you test it on other devices?

Comment: I will try to get other devices, yeah my best guess is also that it is something with device :). Ok, thanks anyway, thanks for your support

Comment: By the way maybe you know how could I use log on discharging phone? Because whenever I want to log my phone is although charging because of the USB that I am connecting with.